# CSS styles path for ACE components

Tags: css, icefaces, icefaces-3

I  like to add css default styles for ace components ( icefaces) in jsf page and i dont know what path of css styles i should include in jsf page. For ice components  i have following css path.

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/xmlhttp/css/rime/rime-portlet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what ure looking for ?? http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/ace.theme

Comment: not really,  i have already added it in web.xml. My problem is, whenever i use any ace component e.g. datatable mentioned http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataTableBean# then neither css styles are loaded nor javascript files for datatable ace component.

Comment: I probably can´t help you but from my little experience I could advise you to totaly reset your environment as sometimes those things dont function on the first run, and setting the theme in web.xml should do the trick... I guess u shouldnt have to set the path manually.

Comment: by the way did u set all the pages to use the theme? "By default, ICEfaces will automatically load the "sam" theme on each page configured to use the ACE Components"

Answer (score 0):

In the Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
    <param-value>rime</param-value>
</context-param>
```